# want to remove certain value from the vector in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have vector in the below form:

a<-

```
[1] "[1]"                "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "[5]"                "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""             
[11] "[9]"                "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "[13]"               "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""              "\"0\""
```

I want to remove all the numbers "[1]","[5]","[11]","[15]"...."[1500]" so on  using gsub or regex in R. I have given a try below:

```
remove<- gsub("[0:9]", a)
```

But getting following error:

```
Error in gsub("[0:9]", a) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to make them empty or remove from the character vector?

Comment: Please read documentation of `gsub`, error message is self explanatory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to remove them.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code that generates that vector, i.e. `a <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")`, rather than the output from printing it

Comment: [Did my answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682885/3832970)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I use substring to do this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Substring cannot remove the items in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `gsub` only removes text inside character vector items, it does not remove the items themselves. In this case, you need a `grep`-like solution.

You may use a simple pattern to identify those items:

```
^\[\d+]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FORIaI/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `]` - a literal `]`
- `$` - end of string.

Then, **use it with `grep` command** with `invert=TRUE` option to only keep the items that do not match this regex, and `value=TRUE` to get the values rather than indices.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/JFkpKy):

```
> a <- c("[1]", "\"0\"")
> grep("^\\[\\d+]$", a, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
[1] "\"0\""
```